# Maximo anywhere-offline db clear data

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I want to clear all data from offline db.
Is there any method, i tried "deleteLocalAll".But its deleting from display but not from db. Please advise if any framework method.
ModelService.empty is to get empty list right

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All records are stored in local storage on the device before it is synchronised with the data base, the application currently does not have a function to delete the local storage, just uses the query to filter out the records.
were are you putting the delete function and how are you calling it?